# question on Poisson equation with solution not in $H_0^1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

I'm considering the following quesion about Poisson equation:

$$
-\Delta u=f
$$
in a ball radius $1$ in $3$ dimension, if $f\in L^{2}$, then the
theory of elliptic PDE says that the above equation exists unique
solution $u\in H_{0}^{1}$. Then I suppose that $f=r-1$, where $r=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}$,
this is a radial function, so we can suppose that the solution $u$
must be a radial function, i.e. $u\left(x\right)=u\left(r\right)$,
then I considered 
$$
u''\left(r\right)+\frac{n-1}{r}u'\left(r\right)=1-r.
$$
The solution of this ODE with boundary condition $u\left(1\right)=0$
and $u'\left(1\right)=0$ added is
$$
u\left(r\right)=-\frac{\left(r+1\right)\left(r-1\right)^{3}}{12r}.
$$
It is true that $u\left(r\right)$ is a solution of the Poisson equation,
but by calculating
$$
\nabla u=u'\left(r\right)\cdot\frac{x}{r}=\frac{-1+\left(4-3r\right)r^{3}}{12r^{2}}\cdot\frac{x}{r}
$$
and $\left|\nabla u\right|=\frac{1-\left(4-3r\right)r^{3}}{12r^{2}}$,
but $\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}}=\infty$, this contradicts $u\in H_{0}^{1}$.
what am I get wrong in somewhere?

Comment: The equation can describe an electrostatic potential $u$ with a charge density $f$. Your boundary condition says that the electric field is zero at $r=1$. That implies that the net charge is $0$. Your solution is telling you that there must be a point charge of opposite sign at the origin to cancel the field of the charge distribution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is coming from your enforcement of the second boundary condition $u'(1)=0$, which is not something that must be true.  The general solution of the ODE with the BC $u(1) =0$ is 
$$
u(r) = C\left(1 - \frac{1}{r}\right) - \frac{1}{12} + \frac{r^2}{6} -\frac{r^3}{12}.
$$
for some constant $C$.  If you enforce the condition $u'(1)=0$ then you get a nontrivial $C$, which is causing the problems with the gradient.  If instead you pick $C$ to enforce the gradient condition then you'll get $C=0$, which kills the singular term at the origin.  Roughly speaking, what's going on here is that the second boundary condition is at $r=0$ and enforces the condition that your solution is not too singular.